# Delete specific string in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have some arrays and I want to delete array with specific string.
Code I have try

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hapuskan'])){
$fileset=$_POST['kiwet']; 
$fileset = explode("\n", $fileset);
$cari = $_POST['hapus'];
$input = preg_quote($cari, '~');
$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $fileset);
$tampil = array_diff($fileset, $result);
$handle = fopen ("file.txt", "w");
foreach ($tampil as $key) {
if($key!==""){
$key = $key."\n";
fputs($handle, $key);}}}
header('location:index.php');
?>
```

Sample of my arrays in file.txt is:

```
bandung
band
beattle band
bandung indonesia
indonesia
```

I want delete "band" and "beattle band" only, but with my code "bandung", "band", and "bandung indonesia" will delete too. How to solve this?

Comment: `$result = preg_grep('~^’ . $input . ‘$~', $fileset);`

Comment: Hi Ryan, how if I want to delete "beattle band" ? With your answer it will delete band only. Not every "band"

Comment: `$result = preg_grep('~(^|[\s])’ . $input . ‘($|[\s])~', $fileset);`  Sorry, didn't see that you wanted to include "beattle band".  (^|[\s]) will match the beginning of a line or whitespace and ($|[\s]) will match the end of a line or whitespace.  So this would match the word "band" anywhere in the line but not if it's inside of another word.

Comment: Thanks @ryanjones it works...